# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'pop' in Custom Keras Model with overwritten train_step

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I got this error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'pop' in my Encoder-Decoder custom Keras model while using model.fit with custom train_step. I do not understand where this error has occurred. I need help on how to resolve such errors when we do not know the place of error?

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-561-573fadf7e010> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(dataset,epochs=10)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _batch_update_progbar(self, logs)
    921 
    922     logs = copy.copy(logs) if logs else {}
--> 923     batch_size = logs.pop('size', 0)
    924     num_steps = logs.pop('num_steps', 1)  # DistStrat can run >1 steps.
    925     logs.pop('batch', None)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Link to my code:https://github.com/abhishek203/E-Abhishek/blob/master/Untitled4.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

the return statement of your train step should be something like {'loss':loss} instead of loss